# Which widget to use for display category post with view more?

Tags: plugins, posts, widgets

I am new in wordpress and I have 5 categories which needs to be display on homepage with each panel.

Every category post has its own panel in which only 5 post will be shown and show view more link.

Here is the screenshot which I saw one of the wordpress website.
[image]

This image is of recent posts category. I want something like this on my website. Can anyone tell me which widget or plugin will be used for this kind of structure to build.

For more reference you can look into https://freshersbee.com

Comment: Category Posts Widget is a light widget designed to do one thing and do it well: display the most recent posts from a certain category.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/

Comment: I want the same design as it shown in the above image